# Stop socket connects (force)

Tags: server, scripts, php, sockets

Can you help me to close socket connection force.

I have PHP script which works like listener at port 1234
But some times i need to relaunch this script. So i'm doing "killall php" and then "php script.php &"

but from first time i cant launch script because somebody already use port.

and when i check port by command "ss | grep 1234"
and i see

```
tcp   FIN-WAIT-1  0       1                            1.2.3.4:1234                                      146.0.82.10:47152                               
tcp   FIN-WAIT-1  0       1                            1.2.3.4:1234                                  123.123.123.123:56286                               
tcp   FIN-WAIT-1  0       1                            1.2.3.4:1234                                    146.0.82.11:64941
```

So after  1-2 min they will stop by own... But waiting its not good.

How can i stop them now forcly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
sudo netstat -tpln | grep 1234
```

it will show you service name behinde port and its pid which you can kill it

```
sudo kill -9 <PID>
```

Comment: Sorry, but your proposal dont accept
Because - i deleted all daemons from my side, and this daemons in process i cant see them... but port stay "in use" and i cant rekill them i see this processes JUST in "ss | grep 1234" so your proposal dont stop my tasks

Comment: What I said is robust way to free any port in debian. what is your os type?

Comment: something else, netstat does not return process. it return list of ports and services behind them.